# iTOP - Bulk assignment of User requests to a team doesn't work

Tags: sql

When trying to do a bulk assignment of user request objects, it won't let me select the Team. (see screenshot). Displays message 'No objects to display'.

It works fine while assigning single user request to a team and allows to select the Team.

Also, query to fetch record takes different conditional value for organization_id
bulk assign: o.id = 0
single assign: o.id = 3

single user assignment - works fine
[image]

Bulk user assignment - not working
[image]

**Two Use cases:**

Use case 1. while assigning multiple user requests from more than one organizations, searchbox appears with 3 fields. The first one is about selecting organization and then selecting teams becomes available. In this scenario, respective teams from the selected organization is displayed.

Use case 1 - works fine
[image]

Use case 2. On the other hand, all user requests belong to one organization does not display a field for selecting an organization in a searchbox while assigning multiple UR. In this case, no teams were displayed as o.id becomes 0.

Use case 2 - not working
[image]

This is a bug as per use case 2. It should by default select o.id from the selected user requests OR it should display a field in a searchbox for organization.

How to solve this issue?

I tried both use cases above. I expect the same result for both use cases.
(https://www.itophub.io/)

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.